# How to compute $\int_{y}^{\infty} x^n\left( \frac{1}{x+z} + \frac{1}{x-z} \right) dx$ as a series near $n=0$

Tags: integration, laurent-series

Consider the definite integral
$$
F(n,y,z) := \int_{y}^{\infty} \frac{2x^{n+1}}{x^2-z^2} dx \ . 
$$
for parameters $y>z>0$ and $n \in \mathbb{C}$.

I want to calculate $F(n,y,z)$ as a series about $n=0$, where notice that $F$ is divergent at the point $n=0$(the integral only converges for $\mathrm{Re}[n]<0$) . Mathematica tells me
$$
F(n,y,z)= z^n \ \mathrm{B}_{\tfrac{z^2}{y^2}}\left( - \frac{n}{2}, 0 \right) \ 
$$
where $B_{x}(a,b) := \int_0^x u^{a-1} (1-u)^{b-1} du$ is the [incomplete Beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html).

I am unable to expand this function about $n=0$ using this form, although I have been able to figure out that it scales as $1/n$. Can someone help with this?

EDIT: Apologies, I had a typo and forgot the limits on this definite integral.

Comment: Why $f$ depends on $y$? What is $y$?

Comment: When n=0, isn't the integral just $\int\left(\frac1{x+z}+\frac1{x-z}\right)dx$?

Comment: @Sal Yes, apologies it is a definite integral. That was a mistake.

Comment: Let $f(z, x) = 1/(x + z) + 1/(x - z) - 2/x$. Show that
$$\left. \frac {d^k} {d n^k} \int_y^\infty x^n f(z, x) \, dx
 \right \rvert_{n = 0} =
\int_y^\infty \ln^k(x) f(z, x) \, dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to expand this function as a series of both $\log x$ and $x$.
$$\int \exp(n\log x) \left( \frac{1}{x+z}+\frac{1}{x-z} \right) dx=\int \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n^k(\log x)^k}{k!} \cdot \frac{2x}{x^2-z^2} dx$$
and prove the integral and summation exchanges.